# Formating date for different languages using moment.js or date pipe | angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs, locale, date-pipe

I have a date field from backend response where the format changes as we manually change the browser language.
For example if the browser language is french my date from response from backend would be something like this `23 juin 2021` or `30 déc. 2020`. I have to format in UI to `MM/DD/YYYY` format.
My code to format it to `MM/DD/YYYY`

```
let momentLocale= moment.locale(this.translateService.currentLang)
 schedule.startTime.dateText= moment(schedule.startTime.dateText).format("MM/DD/yyyy")
```

This is not working and its setting value as invalid date to `schedule.startTime.dateText`
How can i format date to `MM/DD/YYYY` where months are in different languages and the language changes when the browser setting language changes?
Is moment.js required or I can do it using Datepipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import the `moment` locale(s) you're going to use and pass the input format to the `moment` parsing function:

```
import 'moment/locale/fr';

...

let momentLocale = moment.locale(this.translateService.currentLang);
schedule.startTime.dateText= moment(schedule.startTime.dateText, "DD MMM YYYY").format("MM/DD/yyyy");
```